# Automatonymous and EntityFrameworkCore Integration issue

Tags: entity-framework-core, masstransit, automatonymous

I get an error as below while I persist states with EntityFramework

> *MT-Reason:*  fault
>
> *MT-Fault-Message:*   Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade,
>   System.String, System.Threading.CancellationToken, System.Object[])'.
>
> *MT-Fault-StackTrace:*  at MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration.Saga.EntityFrameworkSagaRepository1.d__81.MoveNext()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine&
>   stateMachine) at
>   MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration.Saga.EntityFrameworkSagaRepository1.SendQuery[T](SagaQueryConsumeContext2
>   context, ISagaPolicy2 policy, IPipe1 next) at
>   MassTransit.Saga.Pipeline.Filters.QuerySagaFilter2.>-Send>d__6.MoveNext()
>   at
>   MassTransit.Saga.Pipeline.Filters.QuerySagaFilter2.-Send>d__6.MoveNext() at GreenPipes.Filters.TeeFilter1.d__5.MoveNext() at
>   GreenPipes.Filters.OutputPipeFilter2.d__6.MoveNext()
>   at
>   GreenPipes.Filters.OutputPipeFilter2.-Send>d__6.MoveNext()
>   at
>   MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.DeserializeFilter.d__4.MoveNext()
>   at
>   GreenPipes.Filters.RescueFilter2.d__5.MoveNext()

All my tests are passing and state machine is working with `InMemorySagaRepository`.
But when I change it to `EntityFrameworkSagaRepository`, it has difficulties to store and throwing above error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like dll version issue.

Comment: The error message says that you are not able to find `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync` method with given parameters from `EFSagaRepository` check your repository and make sure you are trying to find correct method based on EF version you are using. This wouldn't throw during InMemory since ExecuteSql doesn't exist for in memory

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev I don't think so, removed and updated all dll's to latest versions

Comment: @JasKevs to latest versions of what? The missing method seems to be in the EF dll. Probably you use too new EF version? MT has no upper limit in nuspec so this can happen.